# Getting error while deploy project on vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, build-error

Getting Error while deploying on vercel.
Project is running fine locally and also build is running file locally

Getting this error
npm ERR! code 112:14:30.983npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/sharp12:14:30.986npm ERR! command failed12:14:30.986
npm ERR! command sh -c node install/check12:14:30.987npm ERR! node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)12:14:30.987
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)12:14:30.988npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)12:14:30.99212:14:30.994
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-03-27T06_44_17_530Z-debug-0.log12:14:31.019Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1

I have tried some previous solutions but they did not help

Comment: Can you share what solutions you've tried already?